# Getting an error when trying to randomly select a value from an array

Tags: java, arrays, random

I have main class where I define a 2d array of type Seat and then use a method to randomly select a seat element and set it as "booked"

However if it has to randomly select more than 1 (Sometimes even if it only needs to randomly select one) seat element it returns this error:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at cinemasystem.Seat.bookSeat(Seat.java:173)
    at cinemasystem.CinemaSystem.main(CinemaSystem.java:70)
Java Result: 1"
```

I have no clue what I am doing wrong, probably something with my random generating method, anyhow any help would be appreciated.

Main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        Seat cinemaactual = new Seat("Cinema");
        Seat[][] cinema = new Seat[12][23];
        Seat bookedSeat = new Seat("");

        Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer, contiune, list;
        cinemaactual.CreateTheatre(cinema);
        int number, check = 0, category, id;

        do {

            System.out.print("Welcome to the Theatre Booking System. (QUIT to exit)"
                    + "\nWould you like to purchase tickets or list available seats?"
                    + "(/Purchase/List/Help)");
            answer = scan.nextLine();

            if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("purchase")) {
                do {

                    System.out.println("Please choose the cateogry of ticket "
                            + "you would like, followed by who the ticket is for"
                            + "and the amount required. (separated by a space)\n"
                            + "1. Gold\n2. Silver\n3. Bronze\n\n1. Adult\n2."
                            + " Child\n3. Concession");
                    category = scan.nextInt();
                    check = category;
                    id = scan.nextInt();
                    number = scan.nextInt();
                    if (category == 1 || category == 2 || category == 3 && id == 1 || id == 2 || id == 3) {

                        ticket.SetType(category);
                        if (category == 1) {
                            ticket.SetName("Gold");
                        } else if (category == 2) {
                            ticket.SetName("Siler");
                        } else {
                            ticket.SetName("Bronze");
                        }
                        ticket.SetNumber(number);
                        ticket.SetID(id);
                        if (id == 1) {
                            ticket.SetCategory("Adult");
                        } else if (id == 2) {
                            ticket.SetCategory("Child");
                        } else {
                            ticket.SetCategory("Bronze");
                        }
                        System.out.print("You have selected "
                                + ticket.GetNumber() + " " + ticket.GetName()
                                + " ticket(s) at the " + ticket.GetCategory() + " price.");
                        System.out.println();
                        ticket.BuyTicket(category, id);
                        bookedSeat = Seat.bookSeat(cinema, number);


                    } else {

                        System.out.print("Sorry, incorrect input, please enter an apropriate value.");
                        check = scan.nextInt();
                    }
                } while (check == 0 || check > 3);

                do {
                    System.out.print("Would you like to perchase more tickets? (Yes/No)");
                    contiune = scan.nextLine();


                    if (contiune.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
                        System.out.print("Would you like to list available seats? (Yes/No) (A/G/S/B)");
                        list = scan.nextLine();
                        cinemaactual.DisplayTheatre(cinema);
                        if (list.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
                            cinemaactual.DisplayTheatre(cinema);

                        }
                    }
```

The method that randomly selects a seat, in my seat class:

```
 public static Seat bookSeat(Seat[][] x, int number){
        int count = 0;
        Seat book = new Seat("");
        Random rand = new Random();
        while(count < number){
    if (x != null) {

        do {
        book = x[rand.nextInt(x.length)][rand.nextInt(x.length)];
        book.bookSeat(true);}

        while (book.isBooked());
    }   count++; }
    return book;
}
```

Line 172 and 173 of Seat Class

172: `book = x[rand.nextInt(x.length)][rand.nextInt(x.length)];`

173:     `book.bookSeat(true);}`

CreateTheatre Method in class Seat:

```
 public Seat[][] CreateTheatre(Seat[][] x) {

        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("B");
            }
        }
        for (int row = 8; row < 12; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("S");
            }
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
            for (int col = 19; col < 23; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("B");
            }
        }
        for (int row = 8; row < 12; row++) {
            for (int col = 19; col < 23; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("S");
            }
        }
        for (int row = 3; row < 5; row++) {
            for (int col = 4; col < 9; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("B");
            }
        }
        for (int row = 3; row < 5; row++) {
            for (int col = 14; col < 19; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("S");
            }
        }
        for (int row = 9; row < 12; row++) {
            for (int col = 7; col < 4; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("S");
            }
        }
        for (int row = 3; row < 5; row++) {
            for (int col = 14; col < 20; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("B");
            }
        }

        for (int row = 5; row < 9; row++) {
            for (int col = 4; col < 9; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("S");
            }
        }

        for (int row = 5; row < 9; row++) {
            for (int col = 14; col < 20; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("S");
            }
        }
        for (int row = 6; row < 9; row++) {
            for (int col = 9; col < 14; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("G");
            }
        }
        for (int row = 9; row < 12; row++) {
            for (int col = 7; col < 16; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("G");
            }
        }

        for (int row = 9; row < 12; row++){
            for (int col = 4; col < 7; col++){
                x[row][col] = new Seat("S");
            }
        }

        for (int row = 9; row < 12; row++){
            for (int col = 16; col < 19; col++){
                x[row][col] = new Seat("S");
            }
        }
        return x;
            }
```

Comment: Can you please point out line 173 of Seat.java?

Comment: Or better yet: Check that line out before posting.

Comment: You're trying to use something that's `null` on line `173`. I'm guessing that's the line after you assign to `book`. Figure out why that's null. Hint: you never put an object at that index location.

Comment: Both AmitD's and Sticky's answers cover important issues with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you checked `CreateTheatre` logic there are possibilities that values inside `cinema` can be null. Put default values inside array by having one loop.

Take a example of row `0` you only fill values from `0` to `4` and then `19` to `23`. Apart from that I do not see you filling values.

```
for(int i = 0; i<cinema.length;i++)
    for(int j=0; j<cinema[i].length;j++)
      cinema[i][j] = new Seat("");
```

Update:
If don't want to put empty seats then you can just add null check before calling `book.bookSeat(true)`

```
if(book != null){
 book.bookSeat(true);
}
```

---

*You can print multidimentional arrays using `Arrays.deepToString(cinema)`.*

*As pointed out in other thread use `book = x[rand.nextInt(12)][rand.nextInt(23)]`*

Comment: The problem is that I need some elements not being seats, as there is only meant to be 8 seat objects in the first row. One other reason I use multiple for loops is because some seats need different string values.

Comment: @user1719605 If this is your requirement then just add `null` check before calling `book.bookSeat(true);`

Comment: `do {
                if (x != null) {
                    book = x[rand.nextInt(x.length)][rand.nextInt(x[0].length)];
                    if (book != null) {
                        book.bookSeat(true);
                    }}
                }while (book.isBooked());
                        count++;}
                      

                return book;}}` is that what you mean? Because I still get the same error.

Comment: `while (book.isBooked());` you again check it here. I think you should change the loop

Comment: Any idea on how to do this? Because can't add if with the while loop and I don't know how to run it without a do loop. :/

Comment: In your case you are doing it based on random I will advice you to just use empty seats rather than null. Create Empty object and then fill it.

Comment: Then how would I stop random from choosing a 'booking' the empty seat element? Like the reason why there is null elements, is so they do not get booked.

Comment: You book it in the loop then after the loop you remove the bookings by iterating sequentially if it is empty booking remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is why you're getting the error, I don't know what line that's coming from, but this is wrong right now:

You do this:

```
Seat[][] cinema = new Seat[12][23];
```

Then you do this:

```
book = x[rand.nextInt(x.length)][rand.nextInt(x.length)];
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
book = x[rand.nextInt(12)][rand.nextInt(12)]
```

When I'm assuming what you actually want to do is:

```
book = x[rand.nextInt(12)][rand.nextInt(23)]
```

Consider this:

```
Seat[] y = x[rand.nextInt(x.length)];
book = y[rand.nextInt(y.length)];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the root cause of `NullPointerException` exception is  in `CreateTheatre` method. Please make sure all rows and columns (i.e. 12*23) of the seat array is filled with `Seat` Object.

**Some observations:**

1. This loop doesn't seem to do anything as `col` is initialized with `7` and getting compared against `<4`.

   ```
   for (int row = 9; row < 12; row++) {
       for (int col = 7; col < 4; col++) {
           x[row][col] = new Seat("S");
       }
    }
   ```
2. This loops

   ```
   for (int row = 3; row < 5; row++) {
       for (int col = 14; col < 19; col++) {
           x[row][col] = new Seat("S");
       }
   }
   ```

   seems to be overlapping with this loop as its using same rows but overlapping columns.

   ```
   for (int row = 3; row < 5; row++) {
       for (int col = 14; col < 20; col++) {
           x[row][col] = new Seat("B");
       }
    }
   ```

**In the end, several seats are left uninitialized as below, which is causing `NullPointerException` when being used in `bookSeat()` method.**

```
B, B, B, B, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, B, B, B, B
B, B, B, B, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, B, B, B, B
B, B, B, B, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, B, B, B, B
B, B, B, B, B,    B,    B,    B,    B,    null, null, null, null, null, B,    B,    B,    B,    B,    B, B, B, B
B, B, B, B, B,    B,    B,    B,    B,    null, null, null, null, null, B,    B,    B,    B,    B,    B, B, B, B
B, B, B, B, S,    S,    S,    S,    S,    null, null, null, null, null, S,    S,    S,    S,    S,    S, B, B, B
B, B, B, B, S,    S,    S,    S,    S,    G,    G,    G,    G,    G,    S,    S,    S,    S,    S,    S, B, B, B
B, B, B, B, S,    S,    S,    S,    S,    G,    G,    G,    G,    G,    S,    S,    S,    S,    S,    S, B, B, B
S, S, S, S, S,    S,    S,    S,    S,    G,    G,    G,    G,    G,    S,    S,    S,    S,    S,    S, S, S, S
S, S, S, S, S,    S,    S,    S,    S,    G,    G,    G,    G,    G,    S,    S,    S,    S,    S,    S, S, S, S
S, S, S, S, S,    S,    S,    S,    S,    G,    G,    G,    G,    G,    S,    S,    S,    S,    S,    S, S, S, S
S, S, S, S, S,    S,    S,    S,    S,    G,    G,    G,    G,    G,    S,    S,    S,    S,    S,    S, S, S, S
```

If you want to initialize all the seats then I think you may want to update loops in your `CreateTheatre` as below:

```
       for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("B");;
            }
        }
        for (int row = 8; row < 12; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("S");;
            }
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
            for (int col = 19; col < 23; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("B");;
            }
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
            for (int col = 4; col < 20; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("G");;
            }
        }

        for (int row = 8; row < 12; row++) {
            for (int col = 19; col < 23; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("S");;
            }
        }
        for (int row = 3; row < 5; row++) {
            for (int col = 4; col < 9; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("B");;
            }
        }
        for (int row = 3; row < 5; row++) {
            for (int col = 8; col < 20; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("S");;
            }
        }
        for (int row = 9; row < 12; row++) {
            for (int col = 7; col < 14; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("S");;
            }
        }
        for (int row = 9; row < 12; row++) {
            for (int col = 14; col < 20; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("B");;
            }
        }

        for (int row = 5; row < 9; row++) {
            for (int col = 4; col < 9; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("S");;
            }
        }

        for (int row = 5; row < 9; row++) {
            for (int col = 14; col < 20; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("S");;
            }
        }
        for (int row = 5; row < 9; row++) {
            for (int col = 9; col < 14; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("G");;
            }
        }
        for (int row = 9; row < 12; row++) {
            for (int col = 7; col < 16; col++) {
                x[row][col] = new Seat("G");;
            }
        }

        for (int row = 9; row < 12; row++){
            for (int col = 4; col < 7; col++){
                x[row][col] = new Seat("S");;
            }
        }

        for (int row = 9; row < 12; row++){
            for (int col = 16; col < 19; col++){
                x[row][col] = new Seat("S");;
            }
        }
```

**In addition,** since your rows and columns are not same(Seat[12][23]--> 12 rows and 23 columns), I think you want to change this statement in `bookSeat()` method:

```
     book = x[rand.nextInt(x.length)][rand.nextInt(x.length)];
```

to use `x[0].length` as column legth as below:

```
      book = x[rand.nextInt(x.length)][rand.nextInt(x[0].length)];
```

Comment: Ah okay, so then that will make it go through both arrays?
Also it seems to not throw exception now and output is intended.
apparently 

`do {
          book = x[rand.nextInt(x.length)][rand.nextInt(x[0].length)];
       book.bookSeat(true);
        }
        
        while (book.isBooked());
    }   count++; }
    return book;
}`

Needed to be changed to `do {
          book = x[rand.nextInt(x.length)][rand.nextInt(x[0].length)];
       book.bookSeat(false);
        }
        
        while (book.isBooked(true));
    }   count++; }
    return book;
}`

Comment: @user1719605 Please note that exception is dependent on the random numbers getting generated through `rand.nextInt` method. Please refer my updated answer and also correct the issues in `CreateTheatre` method.

Comment: Question: wouldn't the  `if (x != null)` in the `bookSeat()` method not allow a null element to be chosen?

Comment: @user1719605: That check the array itself to be not null. The issue comes when you access some uninitialized seat and call method `book.bookSeat(true);` on that. I added some more details in the answer.

Comment: Ah, as I mentioned to someone else, the array needs to have some elements not being seats, as there is only meant to be 8 seat objects in the first row. One other reason I use multiple for loops is because some seats need different string values.

Comment: @user1719605 Yeah I understand, but all the seats should be initialized. If you want to keep some seats vacant, then you need to handle null check before calling `bookSeat` as `if(book != null){
 book.bookSeat(true);
}`.